# view is not being updated after updating object from server call angular 4

Tags: arrays, ajax, angular, object

I have declare a Array of object in angular 4 like this

```
 public onlinUsers;
```

I Used this like here

```
<div class="row" >
    <h2>Online users</h2>
    {{onlinUsers}}
      <div *ngFor="let i of onlinUsers">
          <a  (click)="openPrivate(i.name)">{{i.name}}</a>

        </div>
  </div>
```

and updating it here like this

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.on('onlineUsers',function(data){

      this.onlinUsers=data.data     
     console.log( this.onlinUsers)
   })  
 }
```

console.log working fine

Why my html is not being rendered . please help

Comment: What happen if you use `onlinUsers=data.data` without `this` ??

Comment: I im updating it in ngInit function so i have to put this here @JaydipJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.socket.on('onlineUsers',function(data){
```

should be

```
this.socket.on('onlineUsers', (data) => {
```

otherwise `this` won't work as you expect inside the function.

Search for arrow functions for more details.

Comment: Thank you it works can you guide me more because i was thinking we have to put this in ngInit function @Gunter

Comment: and why it consoling log perfectly

Comment: Guide on what? Both lines inside the callback point to the same `this`, but `this` is somwhere in `socket` if you don't use `=>` (default JS behavior).

Comment: i think "this" belongs to angular 4 class . Am right ? @Gunter

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions